# How do I submit an app to iTunes yet have it in my client's name?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I am building an app for a client and they want to submit to the App store under their name.  I'm assuming they have to buy the $99 app license.  Must they have a Mac with Xcode installed to do so?  Do they somehow set it up and allow me access to submit the app / update the app / etc?  Should I bring my MacBook to them and have them create their account on my computer?  Does that even make sense?  I've created a ton of apps but haven't submitted any to the app store yet so I have quite the learning curve to go through.  Any tips / suggestions / etc are appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your clients want to upload the app then hey need to have their own developer license in order to upload the app to the App Store. They don't need to have a Mac since they can use app loader if they are using windows. There is no need to set you up for uploading unless they want you to do the job in that case they have to include you in their team development and let you take care of the uploading. I don't think your MacBook machine is needed unless they want you to do the whole thing so no. And no bringing your machine to them does not make any sense. I hope that this answers all of your questions Ryan. And + 1 for asking a good question although it is not a programming question. :)